# Problems with utf8, php, and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, twitter

I'm fetching the JSON timeline from twitter and parsing it through PHP.
I then want to store the text in my database.

The PHP script is in UTF8, I set the header to utf8 using this code, just in case:

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```

The table in the database uses utf8_general_ci, ...

Not even encoding the text using utf8_encode() works.
I keep getting jumbled characters, like `'autodestruiÃ§Ã£o'`

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you 1000% sure the error is when *fetching* the data, and not when displaying it? How are you getting the value from the database?

Comment: Because echoing the data in the browser appeared as it should, but looking at the inserted record through phpMyAdmin didn't, I thought it had to be a problem with the database. Your "SET NAMES utf8" query did the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to set your database *connection* to UTF-8 as well.

Try sending this query to the server after establishing the connection (and before INSERTing any data):

```
SET NAMES utf8;
```

If that doesn't work, please show the script you are using to fetch the data.

Comment: That did it. But how can I set this as default in the database?

Comment: @skerit using the `--default-character-set` mySQL configuration option: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html

Answer (score 0):

Use `utf8_decode()` or `utf8_encode()` method when delivering the JSON data.

Like

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
echo utf8_decode($json_string);
```

Comment: I don't understand: This sends out a header telling the browser that the following content is UTF-8, but then sends ISO-8859-1 encoded data? What for?